# K-Means clustering multidimensional data with a heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, k-means

I have been trying to implement k-means clustering with a heatmap, but have been unsuccessful.

Here is the initial data set:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/simple.csv

And here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import random
#%matplotlib inline

def truncate(f, n):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

def chooseCenter(data, centers):
    length = data.shape
    cent = []
    while len(cent) < centers :
        x = random.randrange(0,length[0])
        y = random.randrange(0,length[1])
        if data.iloc[x][y] not in cent:
            d = truncate(data.iloc[x][y],2)
            cent.append(d)
    return cent


def distance(val, center):
    return math.sqrt((val- center)**2)


def getDistances(centers, data):
    length = data.shape
    dist = []
    for i in range(length[0]):
        for j in range(length[1]):
            y = []
            for k in range(len(centers)):
                val = distance(data.iloc[i][j], centers[k]) 
                y.append(truncate(val,3))
            dist.append(y)
    return dist

def findClosest(data, dist):
    close = data.copy()
    length = close.shape
    indexes = []
    for i in range(len(dist)):
        pt = min(dist[i])
        idx = dist[i].index(pt)
        indexes.append(idx)
    #print(indexes)
    length = data.shape
    n = np.array(indexes)
    n = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(n, (length[0],length[1])))
    #reshape this data frame into the same shape as the data
    #keep running the find closest until there is no change
    #try heatmap on this?
    #this should cluster it, but to make sure test it
    #might need to do some tweaking to this

    return n
#    for i in range(length[0]):
#        for j in range(length[1]):
#            print('dist[i]', dist[j])
#            pt = min(dist[j])
#            print(pt)
#            idx = dist[j].index(pt)
#            close.iloc[i][j] = int(idx)
    #return close

def computeNewCenter(data, close):
    d = dict()
    for i in range(len(close)):
        for j in range(len(close[0])):
            d[close.iloc[i][j]] = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[0])):
            if close.iloc[i][j] in d:
                d[close.iloc[i][j]].append(data.iloc[i][j])
    newCenters = []

    for key, value in d.items():
        m = np.mean(value)
        newCenters.append(truncate(m, 3))

    return newCenters
#    lst = [[] * numcenters]
#    for i in range(len(close)):
#        for j in range(len(close[0])):
#            if close.iloc[i][j]


def main():
    data = np.array(pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/simple.csv',  header=None))
    data = data.T
    #print(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0], dtype=float).T
    df = df.iloc[::-1]
#    print(df)
#    print(df.iloc[1][9])
#    print(df)
#    print(df.iloc[0][1])
#    heatmap = plt.pcolor(df, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
#    plt.colorbar(heatmap)
    c = chooseCenter(df, 3)
    print(c)
    #print(len(c))
    dist = getDistances(c, df)
    #print(dist)
    y = findClosest(df, dist)
#    q = []
#    for i in range(len(c)):
#        q.append([])
#    #print(q)
    j = computeNewCenter(df, y)
    #print(j)
    length = df.shape
    oldFrame = pd.DataFrame(np.ndarray((length[0],length[1])))
    oldFrame = oldFrame.fillna(0)
    ct=0
    while y.equals(oldFrame) == False:
        ct+=1
        oldFrame = y.copy()
        c = computeNewCenter(df, oldFrame)
        #print(c)
        dist = getDistances(c, df)
        #print(dist)
        y = findClosest(df, dist)
        #print(y)
    #plt.pcolor(df, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)

    l = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y[0])):
            if y.iloc[i][j] == 1:
                l.append(df.iloc[i][j])

    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y[0])):
            if y.iloc[i][j] == 2:
                l.append(df.iloc[i][j])
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y[0])):
            if y.iloc[i][j] == 0:
                 l.append(df.iloc[i][j])


    l = np.ndarray((length[0],length[1]))
    l = pd.DataFrame(l)
    print(l)
    hm = plt.pcolor(l, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
    plt.colorbar(hm)    
#    print(y)
#    print(c)
#    print(ct)
    #plt.pcolor(y, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My line of thinking was this:

My current thought process was to first randomly choose the centers.
Then create a list of lists for each point for the distance to each center.
Find the index of the minimum distance for each point for each center.
Create a data frame of the same size as the data set and fill each index for each element with the index of the center the point is closest to.
Recompute the center by taking the mean of the points with the same center index
Repeat this process multiple times until the index data frame does not change.
Create a new data frame and add the points which have the same center point close together in the frame.
Then create the heatmap.

This did not seem to work though.
Just wondering, am I on the right track or am I completely off, and if I am on the right track which parts would I need to change in order to fix the issue. If not could you please point me on the right track.

Here is a comparison of the maps:

[Here are the maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZlK3.jpg)

The first one is the one my program generated while the second is the way it is supposed to look.

I know my problem lies in some part of the k-means clustering algorithm, and my guess is it is either in the reassignment stage where you reassign the points to the centroids and calculate the new centroids or in the stopping condition in that the algorithm does not run long enough. Also in the back of my head, something tells me that I am not doing this as efficiently as I could have and that I am missing something key. I have watched several videos on K-means clustering and understand it conceptually, I'm just having a hard time implementing it.

Comment: Well... kmeans has a sound underlying theory based on the EM-algorithm. Your second step seems to differ (iterative?). Why? You can't expect convergence when deviating from the original algorithm without a sound theory of convergence. I also recommend to reduce the complexity by dropping pandas and work on the classic representation on top of numpy only. And what does it have to do with heatmaps? Heatmaps are discrete! Discrete-optimization is painful! I repeat: any optimization working on anything which is discrete is painful aka very hard! Avoid at all costs!

Comment: Yea that's what I heard, however this is a school assignment for which I supposed to use a heatmap. Also is iterative not the right approach, my instructor and several videos I watched state that you must iterate through each one to calculate this distance. What is the usual approach?